# Is there any way to get a single file update in Accurev?

Tags: version-control, accurev

Does anyone know if it's possible to get update just for a single file in Accurev control. Presently I update the whole workset , any way if I can get a single file updated at the server end ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is known in AccuRev as a "partial update". You can send either an individual element -or- entire transaction of elements to your workspace. See the CLI & GUI instructions below.

Note that while there are legitimate cases for hand-selecting newer versions of elements, performing a partial update should only be performed in exception/temporary cases only. Using the default "full update" guarantees logical consistency between all newer versions of elements representing the new state of the configuration. Performing a partial update does not obsolete the need for a full update. The best practice is to use partial updates for a temporary period of time, then perform a full update before promoting any changes.

### Individual Element

GUI: 
1. In the workspace that you want to perform a "partial update" on, select the element and then click on Browse Versions icon.

1. From Browse Versions, select the newer version of this file 
   Right-click -> "Send to Workspace" -> Select Workspace.
2. This will update your workspace with the individual element.

CLI: 
You are going to use the 'accurev co' command.

For updating an existing element, you will run the following command based on the version you wish to pull into your workspace.

## accurev co -v

You can find out the specific version by doing a hist on the file.

## accurev hist -fev

For updating an element that doesn't exist in your workspace, you will need to get the hist from a known wspace or stream that is referencing the file. # accurev hist -fev -s

Then use the above  command to pull in the version.

### Individual Transaction

GUI: 
1. In the streambrowser, find the stream with the desired transaction. This will most likely be a stream in your parent hierarchy.

1. From stream browser, select the stream and view the transaction history 
   Right-click -> "Show History".
2. From the stream history, find the promote transaction containing the desired elements and send it to your workspace. 
   Right-click -> Send To -> Workspace

CLI: 
You are going to use the 'accurev co' command from within your workspace.

For sending a single transaction, you will run the following command based on the transaction you wish to pull into your workspace.

## accurev co -t

You can find out the transaction number by doing a hist on the stream.

## accurev hist -fv -s

Comment: Individual transaction seems the apt solution for me . As we keep working parallely on various streams and accurev works very slow getting the update for a workset.